# How do you add a "Next" button in a section in jquery-steps?

Tags: jquery-steps

```
    <div class="wizard" id="createacc">
           <h5>Link</h5>
               <section class="text-center">
                   <div class="pos-vertical-center">
                       <h4>Welcome to the sign in wizard. Please link your account if you're a debater.</h4>
                              <div class="row">
                                   <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <button class="btn btn--primary type--uppercase" type="submit">Link account</button>
                                   </div>
                               <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                              <button class="btn btn--primary type--uppercase" type="submit">I want to add the "next" button here </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                   </div>
         </div>
    </section>  ... more code
</div>
```

I just wanted to add the "next" button within one of the sections as a substitute for the next button at the bottom. I've looked around and couldn't seem to find anything. I also tried to copy the class and the href #next and that didn't seem to work.